# Cause of duplicate and missing messages in multithreaded C++ winsock socket?

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, winsock

```
void TCPConnectionV5::startServer()
{
    /* Initialize Winsock */
    int start;
    sockaddr_in SERVER;
    SERVER.sin_family = AF_INET;
    SERVER.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    //SERVER.sin_port = htons(stoi(DEFAULT_PORT));
    SERVER.sin_port = htons(1787);
    start = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &_wsaData);
    if (start != 0)
    {
        cout << "Error on WSAStartup: " << start << endl;
    }
    /* Create socket that will connect to server */
    _listener = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    _socketCollection.push_back(_listener);

    if (_listener == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cout << "Error creating socket to connect to server: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        WSACleanup();
    }

    /* Bind the socket */
    start = bind(_listener, (sockaddr*)&SERVER, sizeof(SERVER));
    if (start == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "Error on bind:" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        closesocket(_listener);
        WSACleanup();
    }
    /* Create the listener socket */
    start = listen(_listener, 16);
    if (start == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "Error on entering the listening state: " << start << endl;
        closesocket(_listener);
        WSACleanup();
    }
    printTime();
    cout << "Server entered listening state" << endl;

    /* Create the thread */
    sockaddr_in client;
    int clientSize = sizeof(client);
    while (true)
    {
        SOCKET messager = accept(_listener, (struct sockaddr*)&client, &clientSize);
        _socketCollection.push_back(messager);
        locker.lock();
        printTime();
        if (messager != SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            cout << "Client Connection success!" << endl;
            cout << "Messager: " << messager << endl;
            locker.unlock();
            std::thread newThread([&] {this->exchange(messager); });
            newThread.detach();
        }
        else
        {
            locker.unlock();
        }
    }
}

DWORD TCPConnectionV5::exchange(SOCKET messager)
  {
    int bytesSent = sendMessage(messager, msg);
    if (bytesSent <= 0)
    {
        closesocket(messager);
        return -1;
    }
    int bytesReceived = receiveMessage(messager);
    if (bytesReceived <= 0)
    {
        closesocket(messager);
        return -1;
    }
}
```

I noticed that when the server connects with multiple clients, that there sometimes appear to be duplicate messages that send to some clients, which is accompanied by missing messages to another client application. I have mutex lock/unlock in place for sending/receiving messages, but what's causing these duplicate/missing messages? Is there some underlying issue I have to address regarding the threads?

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing the code involved.

Comment: Is this sufficient or do I need to include more beyond this?--the redirect function just calls send/receive

Comment: Why is `_messager` a (presumed) member variable?  It will be overwritten every time you accept a new connection.  Instead, it needs to be passed to the newly created thread.

Comment: What is your evidence that suggests the problem must be in the code that's shown and not somewhere in all the code that's not shown?

Comment: I limited the code as such for the sake of concision, but I'll post more for clarity.

Comment: @PaulSanders given the current structure, do I still need to pass in _messager to the thread?

Comment: @ZacharyZhu Yes, since it will take a different value in each thread.  Remove the member variable and store it in a local.

Comment: @PaulSanders I've stored it as a local variable, but I still encounter the same issue. Is there something else I need to address that you can see?

Comment: Not that I can see, no. You need to show the rest of your code.

Comment: @PaulSanders is there a good way for me to share the rest of my code with you? It's fairly lengthy, so I'd like to avoid having to post all of it.

Comment: Actually, I can see a race condition.  `messager` is likely to go out of scope before the newly created thread gets going.  Try capturing it by value rather than by reference: `std::thread newThread([&, messager] {this->exchange(messager); });`

Comment: Thanks @PaulSanders! That fixed the problem. Would it be possible for you explain what the race condition is and how this affected the performance?

Comment: I thought I explained in my comment.  When you capture `messager` by reference the captured variable goes out of scope at the next losing brace and its value is then (in principle at least) lost.  All this happens before the newly created thread has a chance to get going so the value of `messager` it receives via the lambda is undefined.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the clarification!